# Display div content fit to div in server side

Tags: javascript, php, css, dom-events

I got a news display section in my web application. I need to show the first 2 lines of news in a div, which is 450px X 30 px height, 15 px line height.

I only need to show the first 2 lines. I did with server side string split like:

```
$news=$row['news'];
if(strlen($news)>200)
$news=substr($news,0,197).'...';
```

Its showing "sdasd asdasd ad..." if my news contains more than 200 chars ..

But the real problem is ..

Suppose my news contains more "W's " then the news will go beyond the div and show "WWWW..."

And if the news contains "i" ... Then the 2 lines will not fill even my news contains more than 500 chars ...

I would likes to fill my 2 lines with the text and append a "..." if text contains more chars.

It making my application weird look.

I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created the following for a similar issue.

I inserted the text with say 250 chars in a div with overflow:hidden

I then created a div box fixed to the bottom right of the box with ... Read More or in your case maybe just the ...

I hope this may help with some ideas.